# Download a single identical file from multiple web-servers simultaneously

Tags: windows, internet, download, file-transfer

A long time ago, the download manager FlashGet was able to add mirrors from multiple different URLs and it would download simultaneously (1) from all mirrors. This can speed up connection in case the web server limits the speed.

As FlashGet is abandoned and full of malware, I am looking for a download manager with this feature ever since and couldn't find one.
I tried: FlashGot, Persepolis, FDM and others (2)

Is there any FOSS or proprietary download manager for windows that provides this feature?

---

1 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlashGet#Features

2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_download_managers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**uGet** browser extension has "multiple mirrors/sources" in [features](https://ugetdm.com/features/) while being open-source. Works on Chrome, Firefox and Opera.
**FDM** 3.9, unlike later versions, lists "Simultaneous downloading from several mirrors" in its [features](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/features.htm) and released under GNU Public License. But as old version it is optimized for vista/xp.

Comment: uGet seems to provide exactly that feature. Thanks a lot @Bald Eagle

Comment: Where is this feature in uGet? Can't find it.

Comment: There's "mirrors" field when you click start new download / proprieties of already started download. For simultaneous download, specify number of max connections at the same menu.  @smit-johnth